# Compiled app with latest UglifyJsPlugin for Webpack displays " webpackJsonp is not defined"

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, uglifyjs

I'm using the official Vue [Webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack).

The UglifyJs that comes with Webpack doesn't compile ES6. So I changed it for the [standalone version](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin) of the Webpack plugin:

```
// webpack.prod.conf.js

var UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')

new UglifyJsPlugin({
  uglifyOptions: {
    ie8: false,
    ecma: 8,
    parse: {},
    mangle: {
      properties: {
        // mangle property options
      }
    },
    output: {
      comments: false,
      beautify: false,
    },
    compress: {},
    warnings: false
  }
}),
```

When I do `npm run build` the app compiles properly. However, when I do `npm start` and visit `localhost:3000` I get this error:

```
vendor.dc780f28ecc8d64eb53a.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
    at vendor.dc780f28ecc8d64eb53a.js:1
(anonymous) @ vendor.dc780f28ecc8d64eb53a.js:1
app.470f1cb076c387c73cdc.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
    at app.470f1cb076c387c73cdc.js:1
(anonymous) @ app.470f1cb076c387c73cdc.js:1
babel-polyfill.fc14d31ef0450ee23f4b.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
    at babel-polyfill.fc14d31ef0450ee23f4b.js:1
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.js', Infinity)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I used your code:

`new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.js', Infinity),
    // extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
    // prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'manifest',
      chunks: ['vendor']
    })`

But I'm getting the same error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined`